# Wordpress Can't reflect customize css file in production server

Tags: wordpress

I wrote it like this  at local server.

themes/twentytwelve/style.css

```
body {
background: red
}
...
```

It works correctly.But This code doesn't work at production server.

I don't know why it works.

I want to custom css file manually.
Do You have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

my style sheet is

`http://54.248.234.114/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=3.5.1`

Comment: Hi Nobinobiru. It would be good to see some code if you are able show.

Comment: Hi glitchmunki. My css file can show at this url. http://54.248.234.114/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=3.5.1   My body's background property is red, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the style is being overridden further down in the code. In this case line 1590.

Try adding your style in there.

Don't forget too that TwentyTwelve is a responsive theme, with styles that will kick in at certain widths through media queries.